# Converting List into dictionary with only one key

Tags: python-3.x

I have a shopping  list with three values name, price and quantity.I want to convert that list into a dictionary with the name as the key and the other attributes values.How do i do that

Comment: Heard of a list of dicts?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show your code.  Also, do you mean a list of lists?  Is it really a list with only three items you want to convert to a dict?

Answer (score 0):

Let A be the list you are talking about and D be the dict you would like. Use slice notation to construct the dict.

```
A = [ "name", 200, 100 ]
D = { A[0]: A[1:] }
```